# How to make width 100% of the input field in the form when using Angular component clrForm in clarity

Tags: vmware-clarity

[image]Example

```
<form clrForm>
    <clr-input-container>
        <label>Field 1 label</label>
        <input clrInput type="text" [(ngModel)]="model" name="example" style="width:100%" />
    </clr-input-container>
    <clr-input-container>
        <label>Field 2 label</label>
        <input clrInput type="text" [(ngModel)]="model" name="example" style="width:100%" />
    </clr-input-container>
</form>
```

above is the code sample from clarity form, where I am using angular component for the form, the thing is when I Use form **without angular component** the input width takes 100% when I give style="100%" but same thing if i use **with angular component** the input field is not taking to 100% though I give style="100%".
Please let me know the reason how can I make width to 100% when using angular component for the clarity form.

Comment: The `max-widths` on form inputs was a design decision, leaving input widths to be 100% will make for very wide inputs in desktop forms. The inputs are designed to default to the defined size of the browser while still keeping room for the error icon.

Comment: Also, fyi - the reason it does not work with the *angular component* is because the styles are encapsulated into the components view and do not affect the rest of the application. There is a deprecated technique you can use to override a componants style. Read more here: https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep

Comment: But it seems its not looking good. Is there any way I can

Comment: Sorry, I don’t understand that last comment. What’s your question again?

Comment: I mean the entire form layout doesn't look good if its not 100% width, the whole page looks empty. example the image above currently this is how it looks..

Comment: `Looks good to you or me` is subjective. IMO 100% width seems like it would take up to much space. As I said earlier the max-width was a design decision based on the UX research that went into the new forms design. I understand that you don’t like the decision that was made - there is nothing stopping you from overriding the css as you see fit for your app.

Answer (score 4):

We patched around it with a size attribute for input fields like this:

```
<input clrInput type="text" [(ngModel)]="..." name="title" required size="40" />
```

But this can't be done for other controls.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this gave me 100% width for the `<input>` in a form.

SCSS:

```
.clr-form-control {
   align-items: unset;
}
.clr-input{
   width: 100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<form class="clr-form">
  <clr-input-container>
    <input clrInput [(ngModel)]="field"/>
  </clr-input-container>
</form>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with other components like select.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I did with my forms to make the input controls fill up the 100% width:

**Horizontal Layout:**

[image]

**Vertical Layout:**

[image]

```html
<form clrForm class="form-flex">...</form>
```

```css
.form-flex {
  width: 100%;

  .clr-control-container {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;

    // Override to make select full width
    .clr-select-wrapper,
    .clr-select {
      width: 100%;
    }

    // Override to make search full width
    .hf-search-wrapper > .hf-search,
    .hf-search-select-input,
    .hf-search-input-text-container {
      width: 100%;
    }

    // Override to make input full width
    .clr-input-wrapper > .clr-input {
      width: 100%;
    }

    // Override to make password full width
    .clr-input-wrapper {
      width: 100%;

      & > .clr-input-group {
        max-width: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        padding-right: 0.4rem;

        & > input {
          width: calc(100% - 1rem);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In forms,

```
<clr-input-container>
                        <label class="clr-col-xs-12 clr-col-md-4 clr-col-lg-4"
                            >Employee Code/ID</label
                        >
                        <input
                            hfFocusInput="true"
                            class="clr-col-xs-12 clr-col-md-8 clr-col-lg-8"
                            clrInput
                            type="text"
                            formControlName="code"
                            name="code"
                        />
                        <clr-control-helper>Enter a unique Code.</clr-control-helper>
                        <clr-control-error *clrIfError="'required'"
                            >You must provide a Code!</clr-control-error
                        >
                    </clr-input-container>
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly it doesn't work on vertical forms =(.

Comment: @EmilioNumazaki It works for me, you just need to put  Clarity grid classes to labels and inputs. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should cover most inputs types? Select might need some fine tuning

```
.clr-form.is-fullwidth {
    width: 100%;

    .clr-control-container, .clr-input {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This work for me ;-)

```
<div class="form-outer">

  <form clrForm
    clrLayout="horizontal"
    [formGroup]="exampleForm"
    class="clr-form-compact"
    *ngIf="exampleForm">

      <clr-input-container>
          <label>Field 1 label</label>
          <input clrInput type="text" formControlName="sample" />
          <clr-control-helper>Helper text that shows while it is pristine and valid</clr-control-helper>
          <clr-control-error>Error message that appears after focus is lost and control is invalid</clr-control-error>
      </clr-input-container>

  </form>

</div>
```

Ad my .scss

```
.form-outer {
    input.clr-input {
        width: 100% ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

100% on a full width form is ugly, I'll grant you that. However, let's take the login component / form and convert it to using the angular form

```
<div class="login-wrapper">
    <form class="login" clrForm>

        <section class="title">
            <h3 class="welcome">Welcome to</h3>
            MyApp
        </section>

        <div class="login-group">

            <clr-input-container>
                <input clrInput class="username" type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" [(ngModel)]="username">
            </clr-input-container>
            <clr-password-container>
                <input clrPassword id="password" name="password" [(ngModel)]="password" />
            </clr-password-container>

            <div class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" id="rememberme">
                <label for="rememberme">
                    Remember me
                </label>
            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">SIGN IN</button>

        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

this gives this ugly form

[image]

So how would you style this ? I have tried adding

```
.clr-control-container {
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

to the login component scss, but it doesn't work